# command date not respecting timezone

Tags: date, locale, time-zone

I'm in git-bash on Windows 10 :

```
~$ locale
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"   
LC_NUMERIC="C" 
LC_TIME="C"    
LC_COLLATE="C" 
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=        

~$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.31
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.                              
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.             
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.                          
Written by David MacKenzie.                                                    

~$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date
Tue Mar 31 09:40:41 GMT 2020
```

Why `date` showed GMT time instead of time in Los Angeles ?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How to set the correct local time zone in git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22766678/11725753)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezone information for Unix-like systems (both actual Linux OS and the MSys2-based "Git for Windows" tools) is not embedded within the software itself, but distributed as a collection of "tzdata" files. For example, the data for your timezone is at `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles`.

It seems that the "Git for Windows" package simply does not install the 'tzdata' database. (I'm not sure whether this is accidental or intentional, as it *does* have a set of tzinfo files in the "tcl8.6" subdirectory – but not in the "main" shared data directory.)